# 'LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL' on curl to NGINX reverse proxy on a Docker Container

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am able to successfully get a NGINX reverse proxy running locally with SSL enabled. However, once I try to get it running on a Docker container, I get issues with SSL.

I portforwarded to port 9443 using `docker run -it nginxProxy -v local_path_to_certs:container_path_to_certs -p 9443:443`.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

# Expost port 443
EXPOSE 443

RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d

# Copy custom configuration file from the current directory
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {

  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!SHA:!SHA1:!SSLv2:@STRENGTH;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_certificate           /path_to_cert/public.cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /path_to_private_key/private.key.pem;
  ssl_password_file         /path_to_password_file/password.txt;

  server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name _;

    location / {
       proxy_pass https://example.com; 

    }
  }
}
```

On my local machine, this works as fine as expected, but when running on a Docker container running `curl https://localhost:9443 -vvv` gives me

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:9443/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:9443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:9443
```

Comment: Could you solve the issue? I'm having the same problem but with the simplest config imaginable. I now have the default config, a self-signed cert. My config has about 6 effective lines and should be working....

Comment: @julian-f-weinert Did you resolve your issue?  Im running to the same SSL error for a reverse nginx proxy myself and am not sure what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I will asume that you have solved this by now. Either way Im gonna leave the solution i've found searching for the same problem.
I had this similar error and user mljrg find that it was happening when hostnames were being resolved to IPv6 addresses. He discover this by comparing the outputs in two machines, one was resolving to IPv4 and it worked there, the other was resolving to IPv6 and it failed there.

So the solution was to run networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Maybe this helps a few others like me.